# Can OneNote 2013 use logical markup instead of physical styles?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

OneNote 2013 seems fantastic with respect to its syncing and multi-device capability.  But I am disappointed to see, that it does not seem to apply even the basic logical styles like eg. Word (Headings etc.), but only saves physical style attributes (fonts, fontsize, bold/italic...).

OneNote could be a good substitute for my personal MediaWiki, but I do not want to stop using simple semantics (headings, quote, codeblocks) and in effect lose the ability to later switch to another solution, by losing all logical markup.

Since there are already custom style plugins like [Onetastic](http://www.omeratay.com/onetastic) and it all seems to be HTML after all, are there any ways to introduce logical structure into OneNote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575442.aspx) does not support the logical tags. Instead they are either ignored or maped to "*to the available character style in OneNote*".  I guess it is safe to assume, that this is the same with the apps.

A workaround could be somehing like the [Tagging plugin](https://onenotetaggingkit.codeplex.com/) that probably recognizes its styles and extracts structured data.

**edit:** In case somebody comes across the same problem: I started using WizNote.  It supports Markup and has good syncing capabilities.  On the downside, its main userbase is in China, so there are some things not/poorly translated.